# correct way of using constants in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am externalizing some constants for my app and decided to use an external file Constants.h.

Is this the correct way of doing this? I get a "unexpected '@' in program error. Where should put the #defines in this header file?

```
//
//  Constants.h


@interface Constants : NSObject {   

}

#define height 227
#define width 40


@end
```

Comment: Did the app work correctly when the constants where in other files? Can you show how you use them in your code?

Comment: oops problem was unrelated to constants.h it was my import declaration that was wrong. Did @import instead of #import.

Comment: would I need to the class declaration if in the future I will add some string constants in there?

Comment: In that case yes, but at least move the defines outide the class declaration. But your code will work anyway, it is just better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** You found that the error is not from the file `Constants.h`, but it is better to do the following:

---

Remove the Declaration of the `Constants` class. So that the `.h` file contains only the constants:

```
#define height 227
#define width 40
```

Or at least put them before the declaration of the class:

```
#define height 227
#define width 40

@interface Constants : NSObject { 
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In your Constant.h file, define only Constant like this:

```
#define height 227
#define width 40
```

And import this Constant file in your Prefix.pch file

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

       #import "Constant.h"

#endif
```

Comment: Now, you can use this Constants in your whole Application